How to use texture sampler node with texture type of Data
I'm trying to use a texture as data of floats, but I can't find how to do it.
I created a tiff image of 3x2 floats using python as follows:
import os
import numpy as np 
import tifffile as tiff 

# create image of float values (range of 0.0 up to 1.0)
# NOTE: dtype must be np.float32
a = np.array([[0.1, 0.2],
              [0.3, 0.4],
              [0.5, 0.6]], dtype=np.float32)
tiff.imwrite(os.path.dirname(__file__) +  "\\test.tif", a)

I added this to UE5 content and tested it with the follow simple material graph. As shown, the Sampler Type parameter was set to Data, but I ger the displayed Error.

